# Auto import doesn't work for relative path in parent directory

Tags: typescript

I have a simple project:

```
├───lib
│       test.ts
└───src
    └───folder
            app.ts
            tsconfig.json
```

`test.ts` simply exports an empty class named `Test`, and `app.ts` just does `new Test()`.

The `tsconfig.json` is setup like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "lib/*": ["../../lib/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

I can import the class manually by writing `import { Test } from "lib/test";`, but I want VSCode to show it in the auto-import suggestions. If I remove the nested folder and put `tsconfig.json` in the root of the project, the auto-import suggestion works fine, but something about nesting it and pointing back up to where the lib is causes it to break. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding the paths to `include` seems to fix the auto-import suggestions.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "lib/*": ["../../lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*",
        "../../lib/**/*",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Originally I had the baseUrl as "../". Changing to match this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @jazcash for dropping your solution here! It helped me!